# Python Openpyxl automation fail

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

[image]

Basically, I just started learning Python and was trying out low level automation on excel sheets. I stumbled upon issue whereby my code wasn't working as seen in the terminal

I tried doing type conversions and all but it still does not work. Can someone give me a basic run-down of what I have done wrong and what I can do to fix this

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my machine. After running your exact lines of code on a similar worbook, I got this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ZPm.png